# Отправить нужный мне socket.io запрос с клиента на сервер (node.js/socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Пишу веб-приложение и задумался о безопасности при работе с сокетами. Допустим на клиенте есть код:

```
$("#send").click(function(e) {
    var data = {
        name: "Albert",
        surname: "Einstein"
    };
    socket.emit("send data", data);
}
```

Ну и на сервере он как-то обрабатывается. Вопрос, можно ли как-нибудь, без клика, просто сымитировать `socket.emit("send data", data)` передав при этом в `data` произвольные параметры? Если да, то как?

Comment: без клика это как? При загрузке страницы или при каком другом событии?

Comment: ну да, можно через хром консоль выполнить любой код. Так что авторизация и все дела.

Comment: вам надо задавать другой вопрос, потому что сымитировать легко и с этим врядтли вы что-то сможете сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
 var data = {
        name: "Albert",
        surname: "Einstein"
    };
data.name = prompt("Введите имя");
data.surname = prompt("Введите фамилию");
socket.emit("send data", data);
```